# How to increment a total value and decrement in shopping cart using jquery to handle cart?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have html code for my shopping cart, but i am struggling a bit to increment + and decrement its value from my shopping cart, back end is php. I am using jquery to handle the cart. Also need help to add an item to cart. Basically what i want to do from the below code, once i click - it must reduce the actual total value of the product and vice versa when i click +. To Add to cart, i am using cart badge, the product itself must be on the basket as soon user add that item. I hope i am making a sense, there are no bugs from this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var cart = [];
var cartBadge = $(".cart-badge");
var cartTotal = $("#cart-total");
var cartItems = $("#cart-items");

// Initialize total to 0 when the page loads
var total = 0;

// Function to update the cart badge and cart total
function updateCartDisplay() {
  total = 0; // Reset total to 0 before recalculating
  cartItems.empty();

  for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    var item = cart[i];
    var itemTotal = item.price * item.quantity;
    total += itemTotal;

    cartItems.append("<li>" + item.name + " - Quantity: " + item.quantity + " - Total: R" + itemTotal.toFixed(2) + "</li>");
  }

  cartBadge.text(cart.length);
  cartTotal.text("R" + total.toFixed(2));
}

// Click event for the Add To Cart button
$(".add-to-cart").on("click", function() {
  var productId = 1;
  var productName = "Chick Cosmetics Makeup Brush + Sponge"; // Replace with the actual product name
  var productPrice = 145.00; // Replace with the actual product price
  var productQuantity = parseInt($(this).siblings(".quantity").find(".quantity-input").val());

  console.log("Product Price: " + productPrice);
  console.log("Product Quantity: " + productQuantity);

  var existingItemIndex = cart.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.name === productName;
  });

  if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
    // If the product is already in the cart, update the quantity
    cart[existingItemIndex].quantity += productQuantity;
    console.log("Product already in cart. Updated quantity: " + cart[existingItemIndex].quantity);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, add it to the cart
    cart.push({
      name: productName,
      price: productPrice,
      quantity: productQuantity
    });
    console.log("Product added to cart.");
  }

  // Update the cart badge and cart total
  updateCartDisplay();
});

// Click event for the "+" and "-" buttons
$(".btn-minus, .btn-plus").on("click", function() {
  var action = $(this).data("action");
  var inputField = $(this).siblings(".quantity-input");
  var currentQuantity = parseInt(inputField.val());

  if (action === "increase") {
    inputField.val(currentQuantity + 1);
  } else if (action === "decrease" && currentQuantity > 1) {
    inputField.val(currentQuantity - 1);
  }

  // Update the cart badge and cart total after quantity change
  updateCartDisplay();

  // Ensure the quantity change is reflected in the input field
  inputField.trigger("change");
});

// Rest of your code for updating the server-side cart and initializing the cart
// Function to update the server-side cart
function updateServerCart() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "makeup-cart.php",
    data: {
      action: 'updateCart',
      cart: JSON.stringify(cart)
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log("Server-side cart updated successfully.");
    }
  });
}

// Function to retrieve the cart from the server
function getServerCart() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "makeup-cart.php",
    data: {
      action: 'getCart'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      cart = JSON.parse(data);
      updateCartDisplay();
    }
  });
}

// Initialize the cart by retrieving it from the server
getServerCart();
});




});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Shop Detail Start -->
<div class="container-fluid py-5">
  <div class="row px-xl-5">
    <div class="col-lg-5 pb-5">
      <div id="product-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner border">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="w-100 h-100" src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="Image">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="w-100 h-100" src="img/product-2.jpg" alt="Image">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="w-100 h-100" src="img/product-3.jpg" alt="Image">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="w-100 h-100" src="img/product-4.jpg" alt="Image">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#product-carousel" data-slide="prev">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-left text-dark"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#product-carousel" data-slide="next">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-right text-dark"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-7 pb-5">
      <h3 class="font-weight-semi-bold">Colorful Stylish Shirt</h3>
      <div class="d-flex mb-3">
        <div class="text-primary mr-2">
          <small class="fas fa-star"></small>
          <small class="fas fa-star"></small>
          <small class="fas fa-star"></small>
          <small class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></small>
          <small class="far fa-star"></small>
        </div>
        <small class="pt-1">(50 Reviews)</small>
      </div>
      <h3 class="font-weight-semi-bold mb-4">R150.00</h3>

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-4 pt-2">
        <div class="input-group quantity mr-3" style="width: 130px;">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-minus">
                                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control bg-secondary text-center" value="1">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-plus">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary px-3 ">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0"
                        data-id="1"
                        data-product-name="Colorful Stylish Shirt"
                        data-product-image="img/product-1.jpg"

                        ></a>
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-1 add-to-cart-btn" ></i> Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: "struggling a bit" isn't really a problem description. Have you written code to try and tackle this? What exactly are you having trouble with? What debugging have you done so far and try and narrow down the issue/

Comment: @ADyson when i look for tab in Network i dont see any back end response and console nothing gets shown.

Comment: Well, which bit of your code do you think is responsible for triggering a request to the backend, and in response to what action? Try to be more specific, please, so there's no uncertainty. Are you talking about what happens within the `$(".btn-minus, .btn-plus").on("click", function () {` function? This seems to be the function which handles the increment and decrement buttons. But that code does not contain anything which would trigger a network request to the backend, as far as I can see.

Comment: BTW the JS code you've posted has a syntax error. Is that the same as in your real code? If not, please ensure you provide a [mre] of the issue you're talking about, so we aren't distracted by things which are not a problem in the real situation, and also don't waste time where we're unable to run the code sample or accurately predict what it will do. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see where `updateServerCart()` is ever run in your example. I would guess it should run in `updateCartDisplay()` maybe?